# Insert else update

Tags: php, mysql

I want the form to update if their is a row for the particular user_ID but insert if not. I have tried with insert... on duplicate key update but failing miserably so this is my next attempt. user_ID is not an unique index but 'ID' in my table is and is an auto increment field. User_ID is just an index that the session is based around.
This is the code I have been using now:

```
if (empty($err)) {

        $thesis_Name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['thesis_Name']);
        $abstract = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['abstract']);


$query="UPDATE thesis SET (`thesis_Name`='$thesis_Name',
`abstract`='$abstract') WHERE id='$_SESSION[user_id]'
IF ROW_COUNT()=0
REPLACE INTO  thesis (theis_Name,abstract)VALUES ('$thesis_Name', '$abstract')
";

mysql_query($query) or die();
// query is ok?

if (mysql_query($the_query, $link) ){

 // redirect to user profile
   header('Location: myaccount.php?id=' . $user_id);
   }
```

At the moment when pressing submit, I get a blank page.

Comment: `$the_query` does not appear to be defined.

Comment: You are getting a blank page because your query has syntax errors and the `die()` is being executed. For one, you have to quote the values - `VALUES ('$thesis_Name', '$abstract')`;

Comment: the_query is further up, I haven't put that I sorry

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried "REPLACE INTO..." instead of "INSERT INTO..."

Answer (score 0):

[`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) is what you want. You will need to define a `UNIQUE KEY` on `id` (if it's not a `PRIMARY KEY` which is unique be definition).

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE INTO is the answer. If you still wish to use your code, you are missing a semicolon in your query:

```
$query="UPDATE thesis SET (`thesis_Name`='$thesis_Name',
`abstract`='$abstract') WHERE id='$_SESSION[user_id]';
IF ROW_COUNT()=0
INSERT INTO  thesis (theis_Name,abstract)VALUES ($thesis_Name, $abstract)
";
```

Comment: I can use replace into instead of insert into. However, I get a syntax error after  $abstract) saying ; expected. thank you for helping!!